# Send JSON snippet as string as part of larger JSON request

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm interacting with a Web API in which all communication is done with JSON - i.e. we serialise data to send them to them and vice versa.

This works fine, but there is a field called 'CustomData' which is a string type, and we want to use this to store 2-3 more variables. The API requires to send through a JSON string which it then stores and parses internally. However, this JSON is obviously being deserialised on their end as an object and we're getting an error saying it's expecting a string but has got an object.

Is there anyway I can mark this string field as raw JSON, and instruct the server NOT to deserialise it?

I'm using JSON.NET

Comment: can´t you just do something like encoding it to base64 and decoding it on your other end?

Comment: Surely only the API documentation/provider can answer this as it would depend on how it was designed.

Answer (score 0):

May be try to encode the JSON string from the sender's side and decode it on your receiving end before adding to your database? That way your overall JSON deserialize won't recognize the data string as JSON.